# Erro Configuração do Datasource no VS Community 2015 C# + ReportViwer + Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

boa tarde. tendo um dificuldade tremenda pra resolver este problema.
Estou em fase de distribuição de uma App e exatamente hoje tive um problema grave.

Gerar um relatório Utilizando o RiportViwer e Mysql no VSC 2015.

Aplicação rodando sem problemas, porém na criação de um Datasource para serem utilizados pelo Dataset, um erro ocorre.

Filed to open a connection to the database
"cannot obtain privider factory for data provider named 'Mysql.data.MySqlClient'.

Não sei mais o que fazer, já desinstalei o connector 6.9.9, desabilitei o reportViewer do VS e habilitei novamente, cheguei a instalar o driver odbc (que particularmente não pretendo usa-lo).

Se alguém já passou por algum problema parecido, por favor estou precisando de ajuda.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tiago S, muito obrigado pelo retorno.

Gostaria de fazer um complemento ao post do Tiago (que resolveu em partes o problma que estava acontecendo).

Consegui perceber o seguinte.
Quando estiver trabalhando com Mysql e VSCommunity (2015 não testei em outras versões), o desenvolvedor ou analista deve ter em mente que as versões do Mysql, devem ser muito bem analisadas no contexto de arquitetura.

Quando estiver utilizando o mysql-for-visualstudio-2.0.4 acima ou igual, você deve usar o Connector/Net 6.9.9.
Versões anteriores ao mysql-for-visualstudio-2.0.4 devem usar a versão Connector/Net 6.9.8. (este foi o meu problema. estou utilizando a versão 1.2.6)

Desta forma para qualquer versão do mysql-for-visualstudio, o seu conectr deve ser minuciosamente analisado.

Obrigado pela oportunidade.

Sds.

Answer (score 0):

Tente esta solução

1. Feche o Visual Studio
2. Remove a intalação do MySQL Connector/Net
3. Instale o MySQL Connector/Net como você fez antes de excluir (típico / personalizado).
4. Abra o Visual studio
5. Exclui todas as conexões com o servidor/banco de dados/conjunto de dados da solução e do explorador de servidor. (IMPORTANTE: Não remova nenhuma linha de código).
6. Restabeleça a conexão com o seu banco de dados, nomeando-o como estava.
7. Restabeleça a conexão com a sua fonte de dados para os `dataset` como estava.